# Create DicomImage from scratch using Dcmtk

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

In order to save CT data I would like to create a `DicomImage` from scratch, similar like this can be done using `DRTImageIOD`. However, `DicomImage` does not have a default constructor. From the documentation it looks like the constructor can only load existing data. Is it possible to use `DicomImage` directly, or is going low-level through `DcmFileFormat` the only viable approach? (I am using Dcmtk 3.6.1)

Comment: This may or may not be of help but I have had some success using the command line tools: `img2dcm` -> `dcmodify` -> `dcmdjpeg`. I'm sorry I don't have a specific invocation for you. I have just been making them for testing using `-vlp` (visible light, so, not a device modality); I couldn't rattle off a CT recipe right now but I am sure it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the documentation, the purpose of the [DicomImage](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/classDicomImage.html) class is visualization (i.e. rendering) of DICOM images, not creating CT image objects (or instances of any other DICOM image IOD).

Since you are using the latest (?) DCMTK snapshot, you might want to have a look at the [dcmiod](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/mod_dcmiod.html) module, which provides a higher-level API than [dcmdata](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/mod_dcmdata.html).