# How should IODEnhUSImageModule be utilized?

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I am using the DCMTK `dcmiod` module (from the latest snapshot), which provides an API for reading/writing images on a higher level than `dcmdata` (as advised by the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645977/create-dicomimage-from-scratch-using-dcmtk)). I now use `DcmIODImage` with `IODGeneralImageModule` and `IODImagePixelModule`, but can't find functions regarding scaling of pixel data.

In the DCMTK source code I found the `IODEnhUSImageModule` class, which provides access to e.g. `DCM_RescaleSlope`. (How) Is it possible to use this class in the context of `dcmiod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered here: http://forum.dcmtk.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=4389

> the classes in dcmiod do not have support for pixel data operations.
>
> DcmIODCommon and DcmIODImage are just arranging common DICOM modules
>   (in the form of classes from dcmiod). DcmIODCommon for non-image IODs,
>   and DcmIODImage for image-based IODs. DcmIODImage supports (parts of
>   the) Image Pixel Module (through class IODImagePixelModule) but that
>   module implementation misses support for the Pixel Data element but
>   only provides access to "meta" info like Rows, Columns, Bits Allocated
>   and so on.
>
> As an example, how you can use DcmIODImage to write your own,
>   IOD-specific API with support for Pixel Data, you can look at
>   DcmSegmentation (dcmseg/libsrc/segdoc.cc) which derives from
>   DcmIODImage and uses its API to set, read and write common image IOD
>   attributes. Pixel data is added by addFrame() calls on DcmSegmentation
>   which implements all (very simple in that case) pixel data logic
>   itself.